# FTP using Socket Progarmming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, wininet

So I was trying to implement a basic file read program using socket programming. I am using TCP to connect to a server. The client sends the name of file and server reads it and sends its contents back to the client.
The problem is I am getting an error in server program as:

> Segmentation fault: 11

Here are the programs:

**Server.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
int main()
{
    int s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port=htons(1999);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    socklen_t slen=sizeof(saddr);

    bind(s,(struct sockaddr*)&saddr,slen);
    printf("Server Running..\n");

    listen(s,5);

    struct sockaddr_in caddr;
    socklen_t clen=sizeof(caddr);
    int ad=accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&caddr,&clen);
    printf("Client Connected\n");

    FILE *fp;
    char buff[1024],file[1000];
    while(1)
    {
    bzero(&buff,sizeof(buff));
    bzero(&file,sizeof(file));

    recv(ad,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    fp=fopen(buff,"r");
    fread(file,sizeof(file),1,fp);
    send(ad,file,sizeof(file),0);
    }
    close(s);
}
```

**Client.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<strings.h>
int main()
{
    int s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port=htons(1999);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    socklen_t slen=sizeof(saddr);

    connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&saddr,slen);
    char b[1024],f[1000];

    while(1)
    {
        bzero(&b,sizeof(b));
        bzero(&f,sizeof(f));
        printf("Enter the name of file : ");
        fgets(b,sizeof(b),stdin);

        send(s,b,sizeof(b),0);
        recv(s,f,sizeof(f),0);

        printf("The contents are : %s", f);

    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the possible error I am doing here?

Comment: Use a debugger to first find the place in code where the crash occurs...

Comment: If i am using a static file name it works. But if i am taking input from user, sending it to server and opening it via 'buff' then it is crashing.

Comment: Here's a thought: Try checking those naked IO calls for their actual success/failure status. Ex: you assume you opened the file successfully. If not, you `fread` on a null pointer. Ignoring [Spencers Sixth Commandment](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html) is *never* advised.

Comment: why do you entitle the question FTP ?  this has nothing to do wiht FTP  protocol....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check the result of `fopen().` It is probably failing because the client is using `fgets()` and that leaves the newline char in the input buffer. So the filename has an extra `\n` at the end. Also, you never close the file.